# AngularJS - tweaking data retrieved from service

Tags: angularjs, service, angular-promise, ngresource

I've got a service which retrieves objects in an array.

```
appServices.factory('FooService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    var resource = $resource('/api/user/:username/foos/:id', {username: '@username'}, {
        delete: { method: 'DELETE', params: {id: '@id'} },
        get: { method: 'GET', params: {id: '@id'} },
        foosOfTheWeek: {method: 'GET', params: {dateFrom: '@dateFrom', dateTo: '@dateTo'}, isArray: true}
    });
    return resource;
}]);
```

let's say that every foo is like this:

```
{ id: 2, date: '2015-05-13', attr1: "bar1", attr2: "hello" }
```

I need the foos that "foosOfTheWeek" returns to be included in a different array of objects, like this:

```
[
    {date:'2015-05-10', foos: [ { id: 2, date: '2015-05-10', attr1: "bar1", attr2: "hello1" } ]}, 
    {date:'2015-05-11', foos: []}, 
    {date:'2015-05-12', foos: [ { id: 3, date: '2015-05-12', attr1: "bar2", attr2: "hello2" }, { id: 4, date: '2015-05-12', attr1: "bar3", attr2: "hello3" } ]}, 
    {date:'2015-05-13', foos: []}, 
    {date:'2015-05-14', foos: []}, 
    {date:'2015-05-15', foos: []}, 
    {date:'2015-05-16', foos: []}, 
]
```

I have a function that makes that conversion, but I don't know how to make my service to return the last array if I call it from a controller like this:

```
FooService.<FunctionForLastArray>()
```

---

EDIT:

I've tried this approach, that returns the list that I want, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to solve it, since I'm returning the list by itself and not a promise.

On my service declaration I've added:

- A function that returns a list of objects: `{ date: <dateValue>, foos: <listOfFoos> }`
- A function inside the returned resource.

So basically I'm calling this from a controller as:

```
FooCtrl.foosByWeek = FooService.foosOfTheWeek(filters);
```

Where filters is an object with some constraints (dateFrom, dateTo, user)

```
resource.foosOfTheWeek = function (filters){
    var days = getDaysOfTheWeek(filters.dateFrom, filters.dateTo);
    this.foosOfTheWeek(filters, function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var i = moment(data[i].date).isoWeekday() - 1;
            days[indexDay].foos.push(data[i]); // put the foo in the proper day
        }
    });
    return days;
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Following will map the data to array shown:

```
var data= /*[ rest response ]*/;

var tmp = {}, // temporary object ... dates as keys
    results = []; // resultant array
// loop over data and organize in temp object
data.forEach(function(row){
    if(!tmp[row.date]){
       tmp[row.date]=[]; 
    }
     tmp[row.date].push(row);
});
// loop over temp object to create final array elements
for(key in tmp){
    results.push({date: key, foos:tmp[key]});  
}
```

Can use this in `transformResponse` callback of $resource although I suspect you will have problems using methods like `$save()` and would need to pass objects into $resource for updates

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7eufb5bo/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the tip!
My main issue is finding a way to get that result from a controller from a function of the service (just like query, save)

I was thinking about injecting this service in another service (let's call it "BarService") and then inject both of them in the controller, so I can have the functionalities of FooService and also the query that get the results in the way that I need them, but I guess this is not the best way to achieve what I want.